# Why is `valgrind` reporting memory leak for `java -version`?

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, jvm, valgrind

I am on OS X using Docker for `ubuntu:16.04`.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install g++ valgrind -y
RUN apt install default-jdk -y
```

When I do this:

```
docker build -t a .
docker run -ti a bash
```

1. Why do I get illegal write of size 4?
2. Why do I get leaks?

It is said that `valgrind` is not reliable on OS X, however I trust Docker to be a reliable wrapper.  I'd be shocked if this is not happening in real Ubuntu 16.04 machines.